# TwebGmap component not showing the Map in UI

Tags: delphi

I want to show a google map on my `delphi 10.2` tokyo application. For that I installed `TMS VCL WebGMaps` component. I used `twebgmap` component in my application. I add google map apk for the component in 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key' and place this key as:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);               
begin   
 WebGMaps1.APIKey := 'myAPIKey';  
end;
```

but after running the application no map was showing on UI,                            I place webgmaps1.lunch;in my fromshow event.                                            I searched in many sites but could not find any solution.                        Can any one help me for solving this problem?                                                                                                           Thanks in advance.

Comment: *...webgmaps1.lunch;...* Supposedly you mean `launch`, otherwise I guess it wouldn't compile. Did you set any default position? What other setup did you do? Do you have the trial version or a licensed one?

Comment: Presently iam using trail version

Comment: It may be, the trial version is limited. [Check the documentation](http://www.tmssoftware.biz/download/manuals/TMS%20TWebGMaps.pdf)

Comment: I already have a look on the document and I did the same step as they said.but could not get the map after running the application.is it necessary the licenced version for testing also??how can I worked with my trail version??

Comment: *...have a look...* is perhaps not sufficient. Have a new look at page 6 under *Windows support*, last paragraph says: **Our browser solution for the Windows target is only available in the registered version of TMS FMX WebGMaps. Windows is not supported in the trial version**

Comment: sorry,i cant find anything as u said in the document.can u please tell me where did u find 'Our browser solution for the Windows target is only available in the registered version of TMS FMX WebGMaps. Windows is not supported in the trial version' this one exactly.

Comment: [This document](http://www.tmssoftware.biz/Download/Manuals/TMSFMXWebGMapsDevGuide.pdf), page 6.

Comment: I did mistake while generating apikey.I did not add any api restrictions.after I add all the apis which are mentioned in the document and now it working fine.but I have another issue the map was displaying in system which have google chrome.is it necessary to have Google chrome to  get the map while using TWEBGMAP component??